# How can i simulate communication between azure service fabric stateless services

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have two stateless service.
I'm trying to run an integration test, with the real implementation when i have it deployed to a cluster. I can see that service 2 does its job and service one sends the event correctly.

The scenario i want to achieve is for service 1 to publish an event which service 2 receives, which in turn runs a method, like writing to file.

when i create a service in the unit test level, i can publish the event but never reaches service 2.

How can i simulate communication between services?

service 1 can be a fake object, as long it fires the correct event to service 2.
at the moment i'm creating a method and just call the action in service 2 directly, this verifies that action service 2 is working but it doesn't check that service 1 is really talking to service 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks for that purpose.